# what are the major factors which may cause site slow performance among cities

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, networking, memory

Q:

I have a web application which published on a server .When i try the web application from another city. the performance is so bad and every thing is slow.

Should i make any enhancement to my code or this is related mostly to the network factors?

Any advices please.

```
Error/Status Code: 200
Start Offset: 0.194 s
Initial Connection: 193 ms
Time to First Byte: 286 ms
Content Download: 1286 ms
Bytes In (downloaded): 48.6 KB
Bytes Out (uploaded): 0.4 KB

Request Headers:

GET /sch/ScheduleForm.aspx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1 PTST/25
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive

Response Headers:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2011 15:17:00 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ane2ncmyyoqwckjmv4bijq45; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 4938
```

[image]

Comment: Start by checking your HTTP headers to see whether keepalive is used and you have appropriate directives (cache, compression etc). You can use the LiveHTTPHeaders extension of FireFox for this, it is very lightweight and provides all needed information.

Comment: This may not be related to a city, but to an ISP (what peerings it has, and how well it routes to your server) used in one city or the other. In my experience, this is the major difference, not physical location.

Comment: i mean the dropdownlists binding for example

Comment: @just_name,slow by what standard?  In other words, put some numbers on this.  Example: Clicking "foo" on my LAN gets a 0.1 second response, but clicking "foo" on the WAN gets a 2.5 second response.  Use [Firebug's Net Panel](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) or use [Cam Studio](http://camstudio.org/) and an on-screen stopwatch to quantify it for menu dropdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must find if the delay is because of the **network**, or by the **server** it self, or by the **Client Computer** or by your **page design**.

Its rare to have bad performance only because you change city, maybe the other computer have slow connection or bad configuration, or bad isp and you see that slow.

### Client Quick Check

The faster way to a quick check of the network responce is to ping your site, open a command promt window and just write "`ping www.yoursite.com  /t`"  and see the time. And if your server is on the same country must be under 50ms.

### Network - Page design

Now second point of a global check. You can use this site

http://www.webpagetest.org/

to check the speed of your page globally, and get very interesting results, as the time response.

### Server

There always the case that you have place your site on a multi use/shared computer, with thousand of sites and bad configuration, so on peak time the server performs badly. I have see this happens a lot of times.

### Your Web Application

If the site is slow compare with the development computer then is ether because live have a huge database that you do not have check, ether because a hacker have found a back door and is attacking by making empty accounts as attack, or something similar. This is up to you to find if the delay is because of your calls inside your program.

**And more reasons for that delay exist**
One more note, use the tools that exist on Chrome,  Mozilla, Opera and Safari to see the time response of your site when your page load.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is the perfect `time response` range  i mean to be moderate.

Comment: @just_name if the client and server is in the same epirus the network time lag must be under 150ms top, if is from one spot of the Global to the other this can be enen 1sec.

Comment: @just_name The lag time response of your site is better keep under 500ms, (plus the network lag). A fast site have less than 200ms, a slow site have 1sec lag. Then the page must be load under 2 seconds to consider fast, but also there are trick that you show the first part of your page and not wait for the full page to come.

Comment: @just_name This numbers are normal. If you give me the url, I can see it from here.

Comment: When i ping on my server from this city .the result:`time out`,however the site opens ,but the data binding is so slow.

Comment: @just_name yes they have block the ping to avoid the "ping death" attack. You can then to trace route. use the "tracert" and not the ping and you get more details.

Comment: thanks a lot for this info . excuse me I edit my question with tracing.

Comment: @just_name in the trace that you show you have big delays (lag). I suppose your server is far way from you, you have 17 point that is a lot. In my server that I have in europe and different country, the points are 8, and the max ping time is 70ms, not 3000ms ! this is a huge lag. Change hosting server, except if this is your country problem. In that case find a server in your country if you target your people there.

Comment: @just_name I make now a traceroute to your ip that you give me and the speed from here is fine, so its a country problem, or you internet provider delay. Maybe you need a server near you.

Answer (score 1):

Your best starting point would be to find out where the speed issue is coming from. Try Firebug/Chrome debugging tools to see if the time is being taken on the server (ie sending you the first byte of the website) or if it's just plain old loading time (eg images take a long time).

If it's on the server then you have potentially some architectural/coding issues, if it's just delivery time of content then you have network/content issues (compress content with GZip, optimise pngs with PNGOUT that sort of thing).

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

That depends heavily how the geographical location of the two cities is. If the two cities are nearby you will most likely not notice any difference.

If the cities are on different continents you may notice for sure latency issues.

If you have latency issues you can not solve them solely by adjusting your code. You need to do something like e.g. geographical load balancing and hosting different servers at different locations.

Facebook e.g. has multiple data centres.. e.g. one at the West-Coast one on the East-Coast and i think they have one in Europe as well. Depending from which location you come from requests are forwarded to the nearest data centre.